# Powershell: Hash table containing functions to be called with parameter

Tags: function, powershell, variables, hashtable

I have a dictionary like this:

```
function HashHandlerSHA256
{
    param($Path, $Checksum)

    $csp = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
    $ComputedHash = $csp.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path))
    $ComputedHash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($ComputedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower()

    $result = $ComputedHash.CompareTo($Checksum)

    return $result -eq 0
}

$HashHandler = @{"SHA256" = HashHandlerSHA256}
```

containing validation algorithms and the functions to be called for validation. The functions should all have the same parameter and return type.

Now when I have:

```
$Checksums = @{"SHA256" = "..."}
```

I'd like to call the correct function depending on which algorithms and values I have available. In this case I'd have a valid sha256 hash.

Now I want to do:

```
function Validate
{
    param($Path, $Checksums)

    foreach($Hash in $Checksums) {
        $Type = $Hash.Name
        $Value = $Hash.Value

        if ($HashHandler.ContainsKey($Type)) {
            $Handler = $HashHandler.Get_Item($Type)
            if (-Not ($Handler -Path $Path -Checksum $Value)) {
                return $FALSE
            }
        }
    }

    return $TRUE
}
```

The errormessage I get is:

```
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\hashtest.ps1:27 char:23
+             if (-Not ($Handler -Path $Path -Checksum $Value)) {
+                                ~~~~~
Unexpected token '-Path' in expression or statement.
```

I am relatively new to PowerShell. I know how to call functions with parameters, but when stored in a variable, I didn't manage to solve this and when searching online for this, I didn't get the answers I needed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you want Something like this

```
function HashHandlerSHA256
{
    param($Path, $Checksum)

    $csp = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
    $ComputedHash = $csp.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path))
    $ComputedHash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($ComputedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower()
    $result = $ComputedHash.CompareTo($Checksum)

    return $result -eq 0
}

function Validate
{
    param($Path, $Checksums)

        foreach($Hashkey in $Checksums.Keys) 
        {
            $Value = $Checksums[$Hashkey]

            if ($script:HashHandler.ContainsKey($Hashkey)) 
            {
                if (-Not (&$script:HashHandler[$Hashkey] -Path $Path -Checksum $Value)) { return $false}
            }
        }

    return $TRUE
}


#add here your couples of algo/function
$script:HashHandler = @{"SHA256" = 'HashHandlerSHA256'}

#checksum to test
$Checksums=@{}
$Checksums["SHA256"]= 'd6a0a09fb1a7971b497674675d5b5621d865d6020e384137548de9c4ac6d4994'
$Checksums["MD5"]= 'xxxx'

#test list checksum and algo
Validate -Path "c:\temp\hello.csv" -Checksums $Checksums
```

an other solution

```
$file="C:\temp\exludevalue.txt"
$Checksums=@{}
$Checksums["SHA256"]= 'd6a0a09fb1a7971b497674675d5b5621d865d6020e384137548de9c4ac6d4994'
$Checksums["MD5k"]= '11A8D99F80F9B29FCF6A995D2F17B2E3'

$Checksums.Keys |   
%{
    if ($(gcm Get-FileHash).Parameters.Algorithm.Attributes.ValidValues -contains $_)
    {
        $algocalc=(Get-FileHash  -path $file -Algorithm $_).Hash;
    }
    else
    {
        $algocalc='ALGO NOT FOUNDED'
    }

    new-object psobject -Property @{ 
                        Algo=$_
                        OldValue=$Checksums[$_]
                        CalculedValue=$algocalc
                        ResultComparison= $algocalc -eq $Checksums[$_]
                        }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I used the first one as I can't rely on Get-FileHash because I might have things like PGP and openSSL signatures. Very precise examples which helped me learn some new things. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In an example I tried to use the function itself as value in the has table. When calling $x.F, F being the key, the function got called. I understand I need the function as string and the call operator to be able to call a function with parameters, but without, I can just push the function itself?